# How do I make another object follow across x - axis when I move an object using Up and Down arrow keys?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to create a C# console window game where I move an object "M" across the x axis using up and down arrow keys.

I'm unable to figure out how to make another object say "S" to follow me up and down where ever the object "M" is at. "M" will be located at the left of the console window that is X = 0. Whereas "S" should be located at the opposite border that is X = 100.

I have used public int properties X and Y in the abstract class. Moreover, I am using abstract method to do make objects move.

There are two derived classes Martian and SpaceShip. I have got the "M" object arrow key movement working. I just need to code in spaceship class to get the "S" object follow the "M".

```
//In Martian Class
public override void Draw()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    while(true)
     {
       keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
       Console.Clear();
       switch (keyInfo.Key)
        {
          case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
          Y--;
          Console.SetCursorPosition(X,Y);
          Console.WriteLine("M");
          break;

          case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
          Y++;
          Console.SetCursorPosition(X,Y);
          Console.WriteLine("M");
          break;
        }
      }
}

//In SpaceShip Class
public override void Draw()
{          
   //How do I make the "S" follow "M"? 
}
```

I expect the "S" to follow the "M" across vertically but will be located opposite of the window borders.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Draw methods are doing to much. They should only be responsible for drawing the object on the screen. The moving of the objects and the handling of keyboard must be done somewhere else.

Here is my solution:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Martian m = new Martian();
            SpaceShip s = new SpaceShip();

            const int MaxY = 100;

            m.Draw();
            s.X = m.X + 100;
            s.Y = m.Y;
            s.Draw();

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
            while (true)
            {
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.Clear();
                switch (keyInfo.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        if (m.Y > 0)
                        {
                            m.Y--;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        if (m.Y < MaxY)
                        {
                            m.Y++;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                m.Draw();
                s.X = m.X + 100;
                s.Y = m.Y;
                s.Draw();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class GameObject
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public abstract void Draw();
    }

    public class Martian : GameObject
    {
        public override void Draw()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
            Console.WriteLine("M");
        }
    }

    public class SpaceShip : GameObject
    {
        public override void Draw()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
            Console.WriteLine("S");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks a ton. I understand now. But I also need  threading or timer for the S character move a bit later. Like S follows M after 1 or 2 seconds later. Can you please tell me how to do that? Moreover, is it possible to put all these in a separate class rather than using in the Main class?